# iPhone photos still stuck on "Restoring from iCloud"

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, photos, restore

I'm on the second day of processing and it still shows under all my photos "Restoring from iCloud". Should it also show at the iCloud backup that its restoring?  Thinking about resetting my phone and do the back up or maybe I should just wait.

I have about 13k items altogether with pictures and videos. I think nothing is happening because the blue progress bar is not moving. I do notice when I unplug the power it will ask if I'd like to resume for an hour without power.

Comment: There's already several answers provided for the different permutations of this question. Have you searched for any of them and tried the solutions?

Comment: I remember that it took **a long** time (not exaxtly sure how many days/hours) on my iPhone as well, even though the library was smaller...

Answer (score 2):

When syncing data from iCloud, you should remember that iOS syncs large data only when on Wi-Fi and charging. Please try the following:

- Sign out from iCloud, then sign back in.
- Put your device charging overnight with a good Wi-Fi connection.

Be patient and keep in mind that download speed also depends on your Wi-Fi. If it's slow, downloading will take longer.